# ASIHTTPREQUEST gives error (1) when iPhone is locked and unlocked

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, asihttprequest, multitasking

I am using ASIHTTPREQUEST to do asynchronous network connections in my app. For the most part it works great. However, if I am running a connection, and lock the phone (but leave the app open), and the unlock it, I get the following error on my connections:

> ErrorDomain=ASIHTTPREQUESTErrorDomain Code=1
>   "The operation could not be completed."
>   (ASIHTTPREQUESTErrorDomain error 1.)

How can I stop this from happening, or even make the HTTP requests continue to work even if the phone has been locked or the screen shuts off?

Comment: Are you using an asynchronous request?

Comment: Yes--it is asynchronous.

Comment: Is your delegate getting deallocated due to the lock? If so, then you need to release the request in the dealloc controller method. You can log that to see if that's what's happening.

Comment: No, the delegate is still there. If it was getting deal located, then I wouldn't be getting any error at all--it would just crash. Since the delegate is still around, I am getting these error messages via my error handler method.

Comment: Have you tried getting the error like this? What does it say?  NSError *error = [request error]; NSLog(@"Error reason %@, description %@", [error localizedFailureReason], [error localizedDescription]);    I should add that I tried reproducing your error with a normal web server, and also a web server where the page times out (deliberately), and I can't reproduce your error.

Answer (score 1):

Start a background task with `UIApplication`'s `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:` method before initiating the request. End the background task when the request returns with success or failure and you have processed the data from the request.

Comment: This will just create it as a background task, right? I don't want it to run in the background by default, only if the user actually makes the all go into the background.

Comment: And that's what that method does. It doesn't change anything as long as your app remains in the foreground. But it ensures that the task gets time to complete when your app goes to the background. From the documentation: "You should call this method at times where leaving a task unfinished might be detrimental to your application’s user experience."